# Can the factorial function be written as a sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial

I know of the sum of the natural logarithms of the factors of n! , but would like to know if any others exist.

Comment: There's many for example: $n!=(n!-7)+7$:)

Comment: Hmm. Given that an integral is an "infinite sum", I think [$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) infinitesimally works.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This one is pretty important:
$$n! = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} 1$$

Edit: As Arkamis explains, $S_n$ is the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $n$ letters. Each $\sigma\in S_n$ is a permutation on the set $[1,2,\ldots,n]$. Since $S_n$ is a finite set, we may sum a function over it, and the sum of the constant function $f(\sigma)=1$ is just the size of the set, which is $|S_n| = n!$.

Arguably, summing a constant function is cheating. Here's one way to raise the stakes. Let $B_n$ be the set of $n\times n$ integer matrices $A$ such that every sum of a subset of entries from $A$ is in $[0,n]$. Then:

$$n!=\sum_{A\in B_n}|\det A|$$

This is the same identity in a more interesting disguise. Every $n\times n$ [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $A$ is a member of $B_n$, and $\det A = \pm 1$. On the other hand, if $A\in B_n$ is not a permutation matrix, then you can prove that $\det A = 0$.

Comment: I can't tell if you are being sarcastic - but I don't know what that sum means, can you please explain?

Comment: @Euclid It means that the order of the symmetric group $S_n$ is $n!$. $\sigma \in S_n$ means "each element $\sigma$ in the group $S_n$, of which there are $n!$.

Answer (score 29):

Lots of good answers, but the answer is quite easily, "yes."

Integer multiplication is repeated addition.

$n!$ is $n$ groups of $(n-1)!$ objects, so $n! = \sum_{k=1}^n (n-1)!$.

Then, $(n-1)!$ is $n-1$ groups of $(n-2)!$ objects, so $n! = \sum_{k_1=1}^n \sum_{k_2 = 1}^{n-1} (n-2)!$, and so on.

---

Example:

$$4! = \sum_{k_1 = 1}^4 3! = 3!+3!+3!+3! = 4\cdot 3!.$$
$$\begin{align*}
4! &= \sum_{k_1=1}^4 \sum_{k_2=1}^3 2! \\
&= \sum_{k_1=1}^4 2!+2!+2! \\
&= 2!+2!+2! + 2!+2!+2! + 2!+2!+2! + 2!+2!+2! \\
&= 12\cdot 2! \\
&=4\cdot 3\cdot 2!. \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 13):

$n! = e^{ \sum_{k = 1}^n \ln (k)}$

Comment: Thanks, but I addressed this one in my question...

Answer (score 12):

$$n! = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1) (k-1)!$$

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: What part about it don't you understand?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, for $n\ge 1$ we have $$n!=\fbox{$(n-1)\times (n-1)!$} + \fbox{$(n-1)!$}$$

Answer (score 5):

Another combinatorially important sum:
$\displaystyle n! = \sum_{k=0}^n\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$, where $\displaystyle\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ is the (unsigned) [Stirling symbol of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), which can be defined (for instance) by the relation $x(x+1)\ldots(x+n-1) = \sum_{k=0}^n\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\bigr] x^k$. (And of course, by setting $x=1$ in this relation we get the initial sum.)  The combinatorial significance is that $\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ counts the number of permutations of the numbers $1..n$ with $k$ distinct cycles; the relation $\displaystyle n! = \sum_{k=0}^n\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ thus says that the total number of permutations is just the sum over all $k$ of the number of permutations into $k$ cycles.

Comment: I think this is a very important answer since one typical motivation for this question is the question for an analogy of $2^n=\sum_k \binom{n}{k}$ for $n! $.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want, we can write $n!$ using [this infinite series](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20of%20gamma%28n%2b1%29)

Comment: I doubt that the series converges - it is probably an asymptotic series.

Comment: The series "at $n=\infty$" is an asymptotic series.  The series "at $n=0$" and the series "at $n=-1$" have radius of convergence $1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$n!=\prod_{p<n}p^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lfloor{n\over p^k}\rfloor}$$

Comment: Can you provide an example for a small number like 8?

Comment: This comes from prime factorization of $n!$. Any $p^e<n$ will divide $n!$. And $e=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lfloor{n\over p^k}\rfloor.$

Comment: $8! = 2^{4+2+1} 3^{2} 5^{1} 7^{1}$.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the following formula:
$$n!=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-k}\binom{n+1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i^{n},\ n\in N.$$

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I found it googling for summation definitions of the factorial function, and thought a good answer would be the following formula, which I discovered several years ago and I haven't seen anywhere else:

$n!=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{n+k} k^n$

I never took the time to find a proof, but it certainly works. It would be interesting if anyone with decent math skills (that is, better than me) could shed some light on it.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702010v1

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(n+2)!}{2} =  (n+1)! + \sum_{i=1}^n i\,n!$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good reference document from a few years back: [Factorials as sums](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702010v1) by Roberto Anglani and Margherita Barile.

> In this paper we give an additive representation of the factorial, which can be proven by a simple quick analytical argument. We also present some generalizations, which are linked, on the one hand to an arithmetical theorem proven by Euler (decomposition of primes as the sum of two squares), and, on the other hand, to modern combinatorics (Stirling numbers).

Answer (score 0):

$$(v+1)! = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^v (v-k-1)! (v-k)^2$$

Comment: Explaining *why* this formula is true would be a good improvement to this answer.

Comment: Sorry i have dyslexia ,change the left side of the equation with ν!

Answer (score 0):

It's weird nobody speak about the Eulerian number which have an identity already found earlier here see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number